# Formatting an array as JSON for input into Google Charts API?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, google-visualization

Noticed that integer values need to be integers in the `json`, however I am using strings.

The raw array is:

```
   '[{"sctr":"Asset Managers","amount":"1586500"},{"sctr":"Auto 
    Parts","amount":"1618000"},{"sctr":"Business Support 
    Services","amount":"1012020"},{"sctr":"Coal","amount":"1043550"},
    {"sctr":"Consumer Finance","amount":"2285000"},...
```

I then use the following code, to remove keys `sctr` and `amount`:

```
        $sector_final = array();
        array_push($sector_final, array("Sector", "Amount"));
        foreach( $sector_data as $row){
            array_push($sector_final, array_values($row));
        }
        var_dump(json_encode($sector_final));'
```

Giving:

```
'[["Sector","Amount"],["Asset Managers","1586500"],["Auto
 Parts","1618000"],["Business Support Services","1012020"],
["Coal","1043550"],["Consumer Finance","2285000"],
```

However the amounts must not be in quotation marks for the Google Chart Api to work.

How can I do that, also is there a more efficient way of removing the keys for the json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to cast that particular element into `int` before feeding/puhsing it:

```
$sector_final = array();
array_push($sector_final, array("Sector", "Amount"));
foreach( $sector_data as $row){
    $row['amount'] = (int) $row['amount']; // cast it
    array_push($sector_final, array_values($row));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sector_final = array();

    //array_push($sector_final, array("Sector", "Amount"));
    foreach( $sector_data as $row){

        $final = array("Sector" => "' . $row['sector'] . '",
                       "Amount" => $row['amount']);

        array_push($sector_final, $final);
    }
    var_dump(json_encode($sector_final));
```